# Css div center alignment not working

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make horizontal menu in center of page but 'div align=center' not working properly.

```css
.nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica
Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #fff; background: #2f3036; text-decoration: none; } .nav li:hover ul a { background: #f3f3f3; color: #2f3036; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; } .nav div ul {display:block;} .nav li ul { display: none; } .nav
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .nav li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .nav ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">A2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

[sample code](https://codepen.io/mahan885/pen/QKwpPO?editors=0100)
I have tried to make horizontal menu in center of page but 'div align=center' not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute;` from your ul and add these minor changes

```
.nav{
    width: 100%;
}
.nav ul {   
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Here's the solved [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vbs9f1es/2/)

Comment: you want sub menu also in the center wrt its parent?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute;`. It doesn't take any margin or padding values.

```css
.nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0 auto;
display:table;
}
```

Here solved fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Prasathvkl/029nwajb/)

Answer (score 0):

please remove the ul `position: absolute;` style other styling left as it is. These are the additional changes you have to do.

```
.nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
}
.nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as the below:

```
.nav {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #19c589;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">A1</a>
      <a href="#">A2</a>
      <a href="#">A3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">New</a></li>
</ul>
```